# Database Suggestions for persisting Map<String,String<Object>> off heap

Tags: database, caching, database-design, redis, in-memory-database

I am running an inventory service, I will get individual messages of inventory state of each item from each store. I need to aggregate at the item_id level. I need to retrieve the aggregated info at ~10ms.

I basically need to do this `List<item_store_level_inventory> --> Map<item_id,Map<store_id>>` (so that I can update the inner Map.Entry with O(1) operation and retrieve the Outer Map.Entry with O(1) operation. I looked at Redis

1. Having item_id as the key and Stringified Array of item_store as the Value. **Cons**: I will have a race condition, I have to have distributed lock on item_id which I am trying to stay away from
2. Using Hashes. item_id will be the Hash Id and store_id will be individual Hashes. **Cons**: item_id level retrieval is O(n). I haven't profiled it yet though

### This is my stats:

**count(items)** - 5 million

**count(stores)**: 3K

**max(stores per items)** : 1K

**count(Unique item-store)**: 70 Million

Just to give you an idea of data size, all I am storing at item-store level is just 3 values. Onhand, allocated and reserved.

Persistent nature doesn't matter much as I can recreate this easily by replaying from a compacted kafka topic.

FWIW, Currently, it's running in oracle. My organization is keen to get off from Oracle and move to an in memory datastore.

Any pointers on an apt datastore will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as you already have a solution running with Oracle, then mapping (no pun intended) that solution to an in-memory SQL database should be straightforward. I'm not convinced that a NoSQL solution will give you any real advantage and would have at least the cons you've already identified.

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt make Redis to work for this usecase. So the question is, if not redis then what else? Sorry if my question was not clear. Planning to evaluate apache ignite next, any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you're seeking a 'free' solution. So, MemSQL,  VoltDB, Altibase, come to mind. This should be a good resource: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases